# Reference static method for ASP.NET/C# event handler

Tags: c#, asp.net, static, event-handling, static-methods

I have a button an my ASP.NET page which currently looks like this:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" Text="Click me" />
```

I want to attach an event handler to the button. Normally, that would look like this:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" Text="Click me" OnClick="SomeFunction" />
```

However, in this case, the method I want to reference is static; that is, I can only call it from `Namespace.Class.Method` rather than `ClassInstance.Method`, When I try the following, I get an error:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" Text="Click me" OnClick="Namespace.Class.Method" />
```

So, how can I use this method as an event handler? Unfortunately, I do not have control over the namespace. I would prefer to use some ASP.NET technique rather than a C# technique, because I am more familiar with ASP.NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Event handlers can also be added, removed and edited in the code behind. For example:

asp:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" Text="Click me" />
```

code behind:

```
Button1.Click += new EventHandler(Namespace.Class.Method);
```

note that Method should take (object sender, EventArgs e) as its arguments

Answer (score 1):

you can run it this way;

asp.net code,

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" Text="Click me" OnClick="btn1_Click" />
```

c# code,

```
private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Namespace.Class.Method();
}
```